# AppServiceProvider isn't being loaded in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel-5

Have you got any ideas why the AppServiceProvider isn't being loaded in Laravel 5.0? I checked the app.php configuration file and the provider is described there. My application name is Tikki.

app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php namespace Tikki\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Tikki\Services\Validation;

use Blade;
use Validator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot(Validator $validator)
    {
        if($this->app->environment('local')) {
            error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
        }
        Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
            return new Validation($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
        //
    }

    public function register()
    {
        Blade::extend(function($value) {
            return preg_replace('/\@define(.+)/', '<?php ${1}; ?>', $value);
        });
    }

}
```

config/app.php

```
<?php

return [
    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG'),
    'url' => 'http://localhost',
    'timezone' => 'Europe/Sofia',
    'locale' => 'bg',
    'fallback_locale' => 'en',
    'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),
    'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
    'log' => 'daily',
    'providers' => [
        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        'Tikki\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
        'Tikki\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
        'Tikki\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
        'Tikki\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
        'Tikki\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',
        'Tikki\Providers\HelperServiceProvider',
        'Tikki\Providers\TikkiProvider',

    ],
    'aliases' => [
        'App'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
        'Artisan'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
        'Auth'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
        'Blade'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
        'Bus'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus',
        'Cache'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
        'Config'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
        'Cookie'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
        'Crypt'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
        'DB'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
        'Eloquent'  => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
        'Event'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
        'File'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
        'Hash'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
        'Input'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
        'Inspiring' => 'Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring',
        'Lang'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
        'Log'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
        'Mail'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
        'Password'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
        'Queue'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
        'Redirect'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
        'Redis'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
        'Request'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
        'Response'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
        'Route'     => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
        'Schema'    => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
        'Session'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
        'Storage'   => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage',
        'URL'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
        'Validator' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
        'View'      => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',
        'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
        'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
        'Tikki'     => 'Tikki\Facades\TikkiFacade'
    ],

];
```

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Still not working :/

Comment: Is it in the namespace 'App/Providers' ?

Comment: Yes, the editor here has removed the first line.

Comment: Do you have any subfolders corresponding to your environments in the config folder? If so, check if the namespace is reflected correctly in the app.php file inside them.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to regenerates the services.json file. So, delete:

```
/storage/framework/services.json
```

Laravel will recreate this file again including your service provider.

Comment: I deleted it and it still doesn't work. I checked the file and saw the provider is also described there.

Comment: please, update your question and show us the AppServiceProvider, your application name, and how you add it at app.php